Geany Plugins are installed but not visible
I have installed (via chocolatey) geany-plugins on geany 2.0 on windows.
The plugins are  aparently installed, but the list of available plugins in Tools->Plugin Manager does not reflect them:


I would appreciate any comment on this.
I tried installing plugins and checking the results on Geany interface.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The first screenshot is a picture of text. Please don't do that. Instead, it would have been better to select and copy the text, and paste it into your question as text (formatted).

Based on this thread, you may need to set Edit->Preferences->General->Startup to point to the directory with the plugins' DLL files.
Note for Linux users: In my case (Ubuntu 24.04), setting Edit->Preferences->General->Extra Plugin Path to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/geany solved the issue.
